# Labels for a multi-(multi-function)-button wall switch

Tags: labels, command

I bought a ZWave wall switch that looks like this :

[image: zwave wall switch]

Classy eh? **EDIT** thanks to @Darryl it has **4 independant buttons!**

This wall switch responds to 4 actions for each of its buttons :

- single press
- double press
- long press
- release (not covered)

I therefore have 12 functions available (3 press modes and 4 buttons) for this wall switch. ZWave connection is not a problem.

I'd like to provide a way to show my **non techie** users which button does what when pressed somehow...

I'd use a model from what I have on my home's boiler but adding 12 functions grouped by type will take some place and be messy: 
[image: boiler labels]

(French column names on the left post-it : "still","blinking")

I am already aware that grouping functionalites is necessary for user remembering, for example

- single press : alarm/security
- double press : multimedia,...

Also, I think I should "keep" button configuration for myself and not tell my users, such as double press.

Here are some actions I am thinking for this particular wall switch:

- turn on alarm system
- SOS (sends me a SMS with "help" when pressed)
- turn on the hifi system and play playlist #1
- turn on the hifi system and play playlist #2 (and so on)
- I'm home!
- go to sleep! (turn off hifi system, lights,...)
- turn on multimedia computer server
- storm! turn off everything!
- turn off hifi system
- misc: free test button
- misc: turn on my computer

**Is there a good/easy/simple way to label these buttons and their type of press matching with functionalities?**

- My users (wife and children) are non techie but they can read and are not colorblind (I am, but its okay since I design the system)
- I can do anything in my house, and this wall switch will just be glued on the wall
- I suppose pictograms will not need further description (for example music notes for "turn on the hifi system" is enough)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok, I'll be the UX guy and you be my user. Let's test this.

Can you guess what these icons symbolize? (in context to your problem)

http://i.imgur.com/OlIO7Lt.png

I'll reply accordingly and we'll solve this together :)

Comment: A few seconds to guess that these are the different states of button press ? In read order : single press, long press, double press, ?? (bottom right)

Comment: Correct! Bottom right is no press/release which is optional. Now, name the actions you'd like to go with them.

Comment: I've edited my question to add new use cases.

Comment: @SocratesKolios This only works if your users are aware of the possibility of "double press" and "long press'. The button design (and your icons) do not educate the user about the extended functionality of what will most likely be perceived as a clustered light switch. This switch unit was probably designed by a technician who saw the possibility of compressing a number of controls into a small space. It's a terrible design that does not allow for new, inexperienced users without specialised training. My solution would be to replace the switch.

Comment: Hi Andrew, considering that this is for home use and a limited number of users I think it is ok. The usability issue in this scenario is recalling the functions, not educating the users dont you think?

Comment: @SocratesKolios No, I don't think it's OK. What you (and the switch manufacturers) are proposing is a press button interface that requires conscious thought to operate - How many times do you think about how to use a light switch? I'll bet the answer is that you don't because it has a single function with direct and obvious feedback. - This thing looks like a clustered light switch but it's functionality is way too complex.

Comment: Oh I completely agree on that. Was it my home system I would have a switch panel with a switch dedicated to each function. Considering though the physical limitations that exist my attempt was to find the best solution to suit those limitations.

Comment: Even with a dedicated switch for each function the panel would require too much thought to operate. There are too many disparate operations ranging between emergency situations (SOS and Storm!) and frivolous entertainment options (turn on the hifi and play...) - There is a strong possibility that the user will end up shutting down everything when they just want to play some music.

Comment: Well, accidental double click is scary (I confrm, my wife doubleclicks on internet links -_-). I have a wall tablet with a webpage displaying buttons, but, you know, unlocking the tablet, latency of the touch screen,... So I supposed this kind of switch could help especially for multi-function

Comment: Warning : I've edited my question with a very important feedback : the wall switch has **4 independent buttons**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my go, if I've understood the brief! Even if it's not right, it's a really interesting conundrum!

I've not put any explanatory notes on purpose.

[image: ZWave Label 1]

[image: Zwave 2]

Comment: Interesting icons for the repetitive button action, even with 4 buttons it is quite clear

Comment: I haven't read the detailed description in the question which actions are available, so I'm kind of like a naive user of these two buttons. I think I understand the first two symbols you use (one press, two presses). I'm a bit unsure about three and four, though. I take it that the third is a press-swipe, and the fourth is a long press?

Comment: Oh my god, this is a very important feedback! Yes it is a **4 independent button** wall switch. There is no swipe feature. Editing my question!

Comment: Probably my fault from the icon I chose, was trying to work out a long press, will post another version shortly.